# Backspace return in JTextArea - JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to remove an specific portion of text in a JTextArea but then I want it to carry up (it's a list of connected users and when they disconnec, they get removed from the list and then carry up). It's like a stack. Any ideas?

I tried this:

```
public void disconnectUser(String username){
        jtaConnectedUsers.setText(jtaConnectedUsers.getText().replaceAll( username, "\b" ));
    }
```

Comment: Which graphical library do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

A JTextArea will contain a newline string ("\n") at the end of most lines. So I guess you would want something like:

```
replaceAll(username + "\n", "")
```

However, this won't work for the last user since I don't think the "\n" will be at the end of the file.

So an easier solution is to use a `JList`. This is a component designed to display a list of items. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information.

The `ListDemo` example code will show you how to add/remove a user from the list. The key is to make the change to the `DefaultListModel` as demonstrated in the code.